# the easiest way to change SVG icons in a span/div on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a Bootstrap website with a navigation like this:

```
<a href="">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <img src="img/messages-grey.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer panel-categories-footer-small">
      Messages
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

And the icons are all named like this:

```
<img src="img/messages-grey.svg">
<img src="img/messages-blue.svg">
<img src="img/settings-grey.svg">
<img src="img/settings-blue.svg">
```

I already got the 'Messages' part to change colors with CSS, but I also need to make the .SVG icons to change from "-grey" to "-blue" whenever someone hovers over the linked DIV. How would I achieve this? Possibly with CSS and if not, jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the `src` attribute of an `img` using CSS.

You can use Javascript, however. Doing it with jQuery makes it quite simple:

```
$("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).data("originalImage", $(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).find("img:first").attr("src", "path-to-new-img.svg");    
}, function () {
    var original = $(this).data("originalImage");
    $(this).find("img:first").attr("src", original);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

try using

```
a:hover{
   background-image:url(img/messages-blue.svg);
}
```

in the css.

Comment: will do from the next time. Thanks

Comment: How does this answer apply to the question given that the question has an `<img>` tag and the answer is using background-image?